# How can I allow copy/paste in Selenium while running in localhost?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, clipboard

I'm using Selenium with ChromeDriver to run tests on my website. I run them in `localhost`. Some of my tests activate elements on the page that utilize the `clipboard` api. This pops up a box asking for permission. I need to somehow bypasss this box and allow the browser to access the clipboard without user intervention. I tried every single option I can find on the web, but they are simply ignored. Except for the last 2 lines, which are not ignored but cause an error.

Here are all my (so far unsuccessful) attempts:

```
        var opts = new ChromeOptions();
        opts.AddArgument("start-maximized");
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_settings.notifications", 1);
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.clipboard-read", 1);
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.clipboard-write", 1);
        //opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard", "*={'setting': 1}");
        var chrm = new ChromeDriver("D:\\Projects\\General", opts);
        //chrm.SetPermission("clipboard-read", "granted");
        //chrm.SetPermission("clipboard-write", "granted");
        driver = chrm;
```

The error I get from using `SetPermission` is:

> OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverArgumentException : invalid
> argument: Permission can't be granted to opaque origins.   (Session
> info: chrome=119.0.6045.105)

From my understanding, `localhost` is an opaque origin.

How can I bypass this access alert?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you getting that error. I set up a simple html file utilising the clipboard on button click ran it on local host and clicking the button from selenium works just fine without any warnings. Maybe post a sample of the html

Comment: Hi. Thanks. my html is very complex. can you send the html you created? also are you using v119?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var clipboardException = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"[*.],*",new 
Dictionary<string, object> {{"last_modified", 
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()},{"setting", 1}}}};
var opts = new ChromeOptions();
opts.AddArgument("start-maximized");
opts.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard", clipboardException);
var chrm = new ChromeDriver("D:\\Projects\\General", opts);
```